# Panda - Lowercase values if the next character is empty

Tags: python, pandas

New to Panda and python so still learning the ropes. However, I was looking at how I could format my imported excel information.

I have several addresses that have the following format "St Street'S" from my address column. Therefore it has this awkward uppercase letter at the end of this. Originally I thought this could be solved with simply just format with anything having a ' before it go lowercase. However I looked more into my information and realised I can't since some addresses do need an uppercase after.

Therefore I was wondering, what code would I need to write so that if the next character after is not a empty value? (St Street'S )?

Hope that explains the issue, will try and post some of my code now but being new I doubt it is anywhere close. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do the street names always end in Street'S ? or do other names also end with 'S ?

Comment: They all end with 'S'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understood 100%, but I think you can use regex to do this anyway. For example:

```
df['Address'].str.replace("\'S", "'s", regex=True)
```

Update:

If you need it to be saved into df['Address'] you need to add inplace=True like this:

```
df.Address.replace(r"\'S", "'s", regex=True, inplace=True)
```

This leads to this results:

```
Address
0   Some Street'S

df.Address.replace(r"\'S", "'s", regex=True)
0    Some Street's
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my addresses aren't all "St Street'S". I did try: df['Address'].str.replace("\'S", "'s", regex=True) but it didn't work, is there a feature I can add before the \S?

Comment: See my updated answer. Worked for me. This assumes of course your address is saved in a column called "Address". Otherwise you'd need to change it to the appropriate column name

Comment: Worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple regex replace to get the data in the format you want.

Look for the pattern "(\w+?\'?)S" and then replace it as follows:

```
re.sub(r'(\w+?\'?)S', r'\1s', input)
```

the pattern is as follows:

\w+? - any number of word characters from 1 to infinity selecting the fewest possible to match pattern

\'? - attempting to match the single quote if it exists or it may be ignored

S - matching the character S case sensitive.

then all you replace is your last S with s

Answer (score 0):

In python, string is a list of characters. Knowing tat, you can find the index of an apostrophe `'`, check if it's followed by uppercase `S` and check if it's followed by empty value. so something like this:

```
street = "St Street'S"
index = street.index('\'')
if street[index + 1] == 'S' and street[index + 2] == empty_value:
    street = street[:-1] + street[-1].lower()
```

The only thing in your question I don't understand is what do you mean by 'empty_value'?